# Creating key:attribute pairs in networkx for Python

Tags: python, network-programming

I am working on creating a graph method for analyzing images using pixels as nodes in Python. Using networkx as graph support(documentation here: https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/index.html ) Take this as an example:

```
new=np.arange(256)
g=nx.Graph()
for x in new:
    g.add_node(x)
h=g.order()
print h
```

As expected, 256 nodes will be created. 
Now, I would like to create node:attribute pairs based on another array, namely:

```
newarray=np.arange(256)
for x in new:
    g.add_node(x)
    nx.set_node_attributes(g, 'value' newarray[x])
```

With the addition of this line, I was hoping that the first node of newarray would be assigned to the first node of g. However, rather, all values of g will be assigned the last value of newarray. Namely, 256. How can I add attribute pairs for each node, element by element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass in a dictionary as the third parameter for set_node_attribute, one that's aligned with the graph. See if this code does what you need:

```
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx

array1 = np.arange(256)
array2 = np.arange(256) * 10

g = nx.Graph()

valdict = {}

for x in array1:
    g.add_node(x)
    valdict[x] = array2[x]

nx.set_node_attributes(g, 'value', valdict)

for i in array1:
    print g.nodes()[i], g.node[i]['value']
```